# Is there any way you can add text to the middle of textarea tag?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is add text to the middle of a `<textarea>This text.</textarea>` . I know how to add text to the beginning by doing this.

```html
<script>
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  
  x.value = x.value + "Some Text";
</script>
```

I also know how to add it to the end like this.

```html
<script>
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  
  x.value += "some text";
</script>
```

But is there any way you can add it to the center of the tag?

Comment: `String.prototype.splice`

Comment: [`text-align: center`](https://jsfiddle.net/5ak13u77/)?

Comment: `slice`, there is no `splice` for strings

Comment: I think you meant to type `x.value = "Some Text" + x.value;` in your first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string by length, insert new string and combine:

```
var str = "Hello World";
str.substr(0, Math.floor(str.length / 2)) + " New string " + str.substr(Math.floor(str.length / 2))
```

**Outputs:**

```
"Hello New string  World"
```